# Capybara check if selector is on page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, capybara

I want to test with Capybara if I have a selector on a page.
The selector is contained in a form as such:

```
<%=form_for @currency.neural_network do |f| %>
    <%= f.label "Days" %>
    <%= f.select(:prediction_days, [1..30]) %>
    <%= f.submit "Predict", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

I'm not sure however how to name the selector such that I can verify its existence with Capybara. I want to do something like this:

```
<%=form_for @currency.neural_network do |f| %>
    <%= f.label "Days" %>
    <div id="select_days" >
    <%= f.select(:prediction_days, [1..30]) %>
    </div>
    <%= f.submit "Predict", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

And test it somehow like this:

```
expect(page).to have_selector('select_days')
```

Comment: You can use `Inspect Tool` in your browser to see which **id** has your select element, then `have_selector('#id')`

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the repo to post a comment so I am not sure what's causing you trouble. If you want to make sure the selector is *inside* the form you can use:

```
    expect(page).to have_css('form .select_days')
```

otherwise just

```
    expect(page).to have_css('.select_days')
```

should be fine.

Please check: https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#querying

I hope that helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

you can add ID as an option to the select

```
<%=form_for @currency.neural_network do |f| %>
    <%= f.label "Days" %>
    <%= f.select(:prediction_days, [1..30], {}, :id => "your_id" ) %>
    <%= f.submit "Predict", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Then test it with

```
expect(page).to have_selector('#your_id')
```